# Loops in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I get stuck when I initialize v(0)=0 and t(0)=0. Is the problem in not creating an empty array first? Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
T= 0.001;
C= 0.004;
n=0;
k=0;

v(0)=k;
t(0)=k;

while v(n)<60
         v(n+1)= T.*(A(n)-C.*(v(n)).^2)+v(n);
         t(n+1)= (n-1)*T;
         n=n+1;
end

n60=n
t60=(n60-1)*T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices in Matlab are starting with 1.

Therefore `v(0)=k` and `t(0)=k` are not legal. 
You rather do:

```
v(desired arraysize)=k;
t(desired arraysize)=k;
```

to pre-allocate. 
and

```
v(1)=k;
t(1)=k;
```

to initialize the first value.

---

so `v(n)<60` will give you an error as well.

you can write:

```
v(1) = 0;
while v(n) < 60+1
         v(n+1)= T.*(A(n)-C.*(v(n)).^2)+v(n);
         t(n+1)= (n-2)*T;   %not completetely sure with this line, you should check it again.
         n=n+1;
end
```

---

from comments:

just set t(1)=0 and v(1)=0, you simple need to rethink from other languages, that the indexing starts with 1. That basically means you cannot use the index as a substitute for "time" you usually need an additional time-vector, which relates your values with a certain time

Comment: So t is the variable for time. At time t=0, the velocity (v) is suppose to be 0. So, if I call v(0), it responds with a value. v(1) is supposed to be evaluated by the loop. So is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Wait, I get it. I see the error in my way. Thank you so much!